# Работа с БД через Sqlite-Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

У меня в проекте есть два класса для работы с пользователями, и библиотека https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/

Первый класс:

```
public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string IP { get; set; }

    public Profile userProfile { get; set; }

    public UserGroup Role { get; set; } // enum
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class Profile
{
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Age { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Но вот тут в чем дело, Sqlite-net не поддерживает использование класса в роли переменной, соответственно вставить данные в таблицу нельзя и в итоге он давится на строке:

```
    public Profile userProfile { get; set; }
```

В качестве quick fix'а пришлось скопипастить все поля класса **Profile** в класс **User**, но вот тут другая проблема: предполагается что другие могут просмотреть профиль пользователя, но вот доставать из БД данные с паролем и передавать в представление класс как-то не охото, что мне делать? Хранить все в разных таблицах?

До этого использовал Mono SQLite и делал все запросы вручную, но получалось очень много кода. **Profile** и **User** хранились в одной таблице, просто для **Profile** выбирались не все столбцы,а только определенные.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу из вопроса - суть вашей проблемы в том, что вы пытаетесь сократить объем ручной работы по написанию sql-запросов, сократить объем кода и повысить его надежность.

Традиционно эта задача решается с помощью [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM) - фреймворков. И библиотека sqlite-net, которую вы используете, очевидно представляет собой одно из таких решений. Ваша библиотека написана специально для sqlite, и в целом решает ваши задачи, но она не умеет отображать реляционные связи на ссылочные свойства в классах.

Решить вашу проблему можно следующим образом. Вместо поиска библиотеки предназначенной *специально* для sqlite, посмотрите в сторону *универсальных* ORM-фреймворков, прежде всего:

- [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/) - опенсорсный, активно-развивающийся и имеющий долгую историю, уходящую корнями в Java (NHibernate это портрированный с Java ORM-фреймворк [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/))
- [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/ef.aspx) - полнофункциональное решение от Майкрософт, тоже с открытым исходным кодом

Оба фреймворка работают с различными базами данных, в том числе с Sqlite. Оба фреймворка умеют делать то что вы хотите - отображать реляционные связи на ссылочные свойства в классах. Кроме того оба фреймворка умеют делать гораздо больше чем то, что вам потребовалось на текущем этапе, например умеют самостоятельно кэшировать результаты запросов к базе данных.

Только имейте в виду, что эти фреймворки в силу своей развитости довольно сложны, и для полноценной работы с ними вам придется потратить некоторое время на их изучение.

Comment: Чем замена sql-lite на NHibernate или EF поможет решить проблему видимости  поля "пароль" на уровне UI? Любой серъезный ORM с lazy load точно так же протянет User.Profile.Password на уровень UI - т.е. проблема никуда не исчезнет.

Comment: @PashaPash Как решить проблему видимости "пароля" на уровне UI действительно лучше описывает ваш ответ. В моем ответе описано как можно добиться отображения реляционных связей на ссылочные свойства. На мой взгляд это основная часть вопроса, а информация про UI дана в качестве дополнительного пояснения. Даже когда топикстартер создаст отдельные модели на уровне представления, он все равно может захотеть чтобы на уровне бизнес-логики в моделях были ссылки на другие модели, и тогда ему потребуется использовать более мощный ORM-фреймворк.

Answer (score 1):

Про профиль вам Andrew Prigorshnev уже ответил, перейдем к паролям.

Для чего вы вообще храните пароль пользователя в БД открытым текстом? Если стоит задача проверять пароль, введенный пользователем - надо использовать криптостойкие хеши.

Хорошей практикой является хранение в БД следующих вещей вместо пароля:

- кода используемого криптоалгоритма - со временем могут появляться новые алгоритмы, на которые надо переходить - но пароль пользователя надо проверять тем алгоритмом, которым он хешировался,
- так называемой соли - случайной строки из эдак восьми символов, дописываемой к паролю пользователя перед хешированием (соль нужна для защиты от атаки методом радужных таблиц),
- хеша пароля (это массив байт).

Иногда вместо трех отдельных полей в БД хранят строку в следующем формате:

```
$код алгоритма$соль$хеш-в-base64
```

### Как происходит установка такого пароля?

Сначала генерируется соль. Потом берется текущий алгоритм вычисления криптостойкого хеша - и вычисляется хеш-функция от пароля и соли.

Далее код алгоритма, соль и хеш-код пароля записываются в БД.

### Как проверить такой пароль?

Из базы достаются код алгоритма, соль и хеш-код. Соль складывается с паролем, который ввел пользователь - и от них вычисляется хеш-функция в соответствии с кодом алгоритма, полученным из базы.

Полученный хеш-код сравнивается с кодом, полученным из базы. Если они совпадают - то пароль правильный.

Далее сравниваются код текущего используемого алгоритма и код алгоритма, хранящийся в базе. Если они различаются, а пароль пользователь ввел правильный - то пароль в БД обновляется в соответствии с прошлым пунктом (это нужно для постепенного перехода с устаревших алгоритмов на новые).

### Что еще надо знать про пароли?

Профиль пользователя и данные для входа должны лежать в разных таблицах. Причем "основной" записью, на которую ссылаются другие, должен быть именно профиль, а не учетные данные. Это позволит загружать профиль пользователя не загружая пароль лишний раз. Кроме того, это же позволит в дальнейшем реализовать и несколько учетных данных для одного пользователя, профили пользователей без учетных данных (заблокированные, к примеру), профили пользователей, привязанные к социальным сетям и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Модели, передаваемые в представление, должны отражать структуру представления.
Класы, описывающие сущности, должны отражать структуру предметной области.

Просто заведите отдельный набор классов для передачи из сервисов (BL) на уровень представления (PL) - DTO - и оставьте в них только те поля, которые стоит возвращать для конкретной операции.

Для маппинга одних классов на другие можно взять [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) - он просто перебросит данные из полей, совпадающих по названию. Или просто написать маппинг вручную (если полей мало).